# Should an answer adding concrete use case be deleted, to make `answers should only be used for answers` intact?

Tags: discussion, answers

In this answer [How to test if a string is a vim command?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13872/how-to-test-if-a-string-is-a-vim-command)

After there is a comment asking motivation of the question. I added an answer to specify that point, with concrete **code, key mapping, examples of workflow**.

But it was deleted, under the reason of

> answers should only be used for answers.

Thus I wonder, is that fair? Or should I just silently shut up.

P.S. I asked the question, accecpt an eariler answer. Then answered the comment's query, instead of edit the question per se, because it would be too lengthy for the body of question itself, in the hope of just to help.

Comment: I re-add the same answer again there. If deleted again, I will add again. Unless the question being deleted all together. If old answer undeleted, I will delete the new one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question is `how to test if a string is a vim command`, your answer only shows how you use the accepted answer in a context which will not be useful to other readers looking for a concrete and working answer. Thus your answer isn't really helpful for future readers unlike the accepted one.

If you want to show how you used the answer you should edit your question. Making the body of the question longer is not really a problem.

Your answer will be deleted and your question locked to avoid an endless posting of your answer.

Comment: To quote [the tour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8GDG.png): *"This site is all about **getting answers**. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat."*